# jQuery Pass object through .On() without event properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I pass the object `self` to the function on the 'Click' event? At the moment it is passing `jQuery.Event` object which contains a `data` property with my object, but I want the object to be `jPlayer`, not `jQuery.Event`

The reason I want this is that when the function is called on the event the code won't work because I would have to access the data through jPlayer.data.jPlayer, if I do this then my `changeShuffleIcon(self);` won't work.

```
ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    changeShuffleIcon(self);

    $(".jp-shuffle").on("click", { jPlayer: self }, changeShuffleIcon);
}
```

...

```
function changeShuffleIcon(jPlayer) {
    if ($(jPlayer).hasClass("jp-state-shuffled")) {
        $(".jp-shuffle").children().addClass("clicked-button");
    } else {
        $(".jp-shuffle").children().removeClass("clicked-button");
    }
}
```

(Cut some code out for brevity.)

Comment: [The docs are clear that you need to access the data passed in via `event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function changeShuffleIcon(jPlayer, isNotEvent)
{
    if(!isNotEvent)
    {
        jPlayer = jPlayer.data.jPlayer;
    }
    if ($(jPlayer).hasClass("jp-state-shuffled")) {
        $(".jp-shuffle").children().addClass("clicked-button");
    } else {
        $(".jp-shuffle").children().removeClass("clicked-button");
    }
}
```

---

```
ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    changeShuffleIcon(self, true);

    $(".jp-shuffle").on("click", { jPlayer: self }, changeShuffleIcon);
}
```